# How to disconnect and connect the wired connection from the command line?

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager, internet

In Ubuntu's system configuration menu, section "Network," there's a section called "Wired" with an On/Off slider button.

What is the command-line equivalent of pushing that slider to the Off position and the back into the On position?

I don't mind a solution that just power-cycles all networking, not just wired.

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

(The problem I have is my connection is mediated by a crappy repeater/bridge; the hardware itself is junk. I just want the command-line tools to write my own work-around of disconnecting and reconnecting the wired connection automatically, which is an instantaneous process and solves my problem.)

Edit: Thank you for all the answers, they all work.

Comment: Check out `man rfkill`.

Comment: Why not try and fix/workaround the problem without killing the network? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and install `iputils-tracepath` and then run `tracepath www.ebay.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `nmcli` to disconnect and re-connect a particular network `device` ex.

```
nmcli dev disconnect enp0s25 && nmcli dev connect enp0s25
```

where the wired `ifname` (interface name) `enp0s25` may be obtained if you don't already know it using `nmcli dev status`

```
$ nmcli dev status
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION   
wls1     wifi      connected    NETGEAR68-5G 
enp0s25  ethernet  unavailable  --           
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restart network-manager by issuing the following command from the terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Restarting NetworkManager service is wrong to change network configuration. NetworkManager tries not to change the network when restarting the daemon, so it tries actively to avoid what your intention is.